# How can I install Ubuntu Light?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-light

How can ubuntu light be installed?

Or is Ubuntu Light only available to OEM's ??

Answer (score 4):

It's only and it will only be available for OEM's. Each Ubuntu Light image is specifically adapted to the device it's gonna run in. So the best way to get Ubuntu Light, now, is waiting. Waiting for Light devices in the market, and from what I've read that should happen still this year.

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading (sorry couldn't find the source anymore) that "ubuntu light" will only be available to OEMs, as it is configured specifically for the hardware to archive even faster boot and so forth.

You can however use the Unity desktop environment with any new Ubuntu installation which is essentially the same (minus the hardware specific configurations).

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/15935/18612) for [Where do I get the source code for Ubuntu Light?](https://askubuntu.com/q/15932/18612), you can get the source code for Ubuntu Light as used by Dell. From there, you should theoretically be able to modify, compile and install it yourself, although I cannot provide instructions on doing so.