# Where do I get the source code for Ubuntu Light?

Tags: dell, source-code, ubuntu-light

Where do I get the source code for Ubuntu Light?

Comment: FWIW, Ubuntu Light is an old term, that refers to a simplified ‘instant on’ version of Ubuntu intended for use on dual-boot laptops preinstalled on Windows https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/download-ubuntu-light-dell

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The repository for Dell-based projects is here:

http://dell-mini.archive.canonical.com/updates

For Ubuntu Light as shipped on the Inspiron M101Z specifically you want this URL:

http://dell-mini.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/lucid-omsk/public/